# Retrieving multiple curated github repositories

Tags: github-pages

I want to retrieve multiple curated repositories. For that

1. I get the curated list from a Github repository
2. Then I go through the list and download the repositories

I need the answer for 1. rather than 2.

I have tried a few ways and now wondering whether I need to use a parser to retrieve the repository paths.

I will like to do this from the following repository

https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions

Thanks 
aaron

Answer (score 0):

> now wondering whether I need to use a parser to retrieve the repository paths.

That would be the easiest solution: you can parse the raw markdown source of the `README`:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdras/awesome-actions/master/README.md

That way, all you need to do is use a regexp like [`\[.*?]\((https:\/\/github.com\/.*?)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/Feqq9J/1)

For example:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdras/awesome-actions/master/README.md|\
grep -oP "\[.*?]\(\K(https:\/\/github.com\/.*?)(?=/?\))"
```